# Using a function to find the average of an array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function

the purpose of this task is to find the average of an array but not within the main, I have to call a function to do the sum and show the average.

I though my code was sound but it just returns " the average is 011014F1"

I have tried a few different ways of doing the function but I've gone wrong somewhere, maybe everywhere!

Just a heads up, im just starting out with programing.

Heres my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


void printArray(int theArray[], int sizeOfarray);
float average(float numbers[], float size, float arrayAverage);

int main()
{

   int array[10] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

   printArray(array, 10);

   cout << "The average is: " << average << endl;

   return 0;
}

void printArray(int theArray[], int sizeOfarray)
{
   for (int x = 0; x < sizeOfarray; x++)
  {
    cout << theArray[x] << endl;

  }
}

float average(float numbers[], float size, float arrayAverage)
{
        double sum = 0.0;
        for (int x = 0; x < size; x++)
    {
        sum += numbers[x];
        arrayAverage = sum / size;
    }
        return (arrayAverage);
}
```

I had the float average function initially set as a float with int for 'numbers', 'size' and 'arrayAverage' but thought i would change them all to float so they dont clash. like converting an int to a float etc..

As i said im new to this so my logic is not really there but i think im n the right tracks.

Any idea why its returning 011014F1 and numbers like that instead of just the average of 1-10?

Any tips much appreciated!

Comment: What you're printing is the address of the `average` function. You have to invoke it with parameters in order for it to work (how else would it know what array is it meant to use?)

Comment: There is a typo. In the `cout` you want `average(array, 10)` else, as you discovered, it prints the function pointer.

Comment: @user3528438: `std::valarray` is about the worst thing of the entire C++ standard library, right next to `std::vector<bool>`. I've never seen it recommended (or used) anywhere, and the fact that it's in the standard library is more of a historical accident. See e.g. Josuttis' "The C++ Standard Library" book for details.

Comment: You should take a different C++ course, one that teaches `std::vector` before arrays.  Arrays are more work when passing to and from functions.

Comment: @ChristianHackl  if you enjoy hand-writing average/min/max functions so much

Comment: @user3528438: What does this have to do with valarray? You would use free-standing generic algorithm functions for this, not the valarray class. The deficiencies of valarray are well documented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of problems here. First:

```
cout << "The average is: " << average << endl;
```

This is simply printing out the address of the `average` function, not calling it. What you wanted to do was:

```
cout << "The average is: " << average(array, 10, 0) << endl;
```

Second, your method signature has all kinds of type missmatches. The expected array value type is `float`, yet you're passing it an array of `int`. This won't work, as the compiler will not allow the implicit conversion from `int[]` to `float[]`. Your `size` argument should be an `int` in the method signature as well, not `float`, since array sizes are always integers.

Third, the `arrayAverage` parameter seems to have no purpose except to possibly throw off your math. You use it as a running accumulator, which is fine, but there's no reason to pass it to the function, it could just be a local value. So, your method signature should look like this:

```
float average(float numbers[], int size);
```

Finally, your math for calulating the average of an array is wrong. You do:

```
for (int x = 0; x < size; x++)
{
    sum += numbers[x];
    arrayAverage = sum / size;
}
```

Particularly, the `arrayAverage = sum / size` is wrong. Or rather, is only right during the final loop iteration. Meaning this is just wasted math. It should be:

```
float average(float numbers[], int size) {
    double sum = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < size; x++)
    {
        sum += numbers[x];
    }
    return sum /(double)size;
}
```

Comment: just hit enter by mistake, anyway i did actually do the math that way in another go but the whole thing was wrong and didnt work so i changed it....for the worse it would seem. as i sadi above my logic and understanding isnt quite there to be honst and that is why i changed the int's to float etc... but i have changed them back now. though on "the average is: " << average(array,10,0) <<endl; the 'array' word is highlightd red and the program wont run...

Comment: it says that int is incompatible with float..... is that because of the 'numbers' is a float?

Comment: If you've modfied the `average` method's signature as I suggested, then it'd just be `average(array, 10)` since the `arrayAverage` parameter is no longer needed as an argument.

Comment: @molebox ah, correct, I forgot that C++ will not implicitly cast an `int[]` to a `float[]`. When passing arrays betwen methods, their types must match. There are ways to get around this using templates, but I highly doubt at this point you'd want to get into that.

Comment: I got rid of the arrayAverage and changed the float numbers to an int, i also tidied up the calculation per you said and low and behold the bloody thing works! Thank you for your help! the frustrating thing was that i actually had the same calculation before but i scraped the whole thing and started again thinking that that was one of my problems. So the reason for me getting a return for the average as 011014F1 was that i didnt call the function correctly?

Comment: It wasn't actually returning anything because it was never being called. You were printing the memory address of the `average` function (look up C++'s call symantics for why this is, too long an explination for a comment).

Comment: @OP: You can also do `std::accumulate` on the array and then divide that by the array size, if your homework permits it.

Comment: @Brandon I'll look it up, ive seen accumulate before but havent used it.

Comment: @Brandon indeed, I had avoided any stdlib helpers since I assumed they'd be against the rules on a homework assignment like this.

Answer (score 4):

`average` is a function, which you need to *call*, and print what it returns.  What you are printing now is the *address* of that function.

Comment: Also, as written, the `arrayAverage` parameter is most definitly *not* going to do what the OP intends for it to do. In fact, their math for calculating average is also incorrect.

Comment: Actually, shouldn't `1` be printed because the function pointer is converted to a bool? This is in fact what happens with VC 2013, including a warning about the conversion (`warning C4305: 'argument' : truncation from 'float (*)(float [],float,float)' to 'std::_Bool'`). I get the same behaviour on ideone.com, by the way. The question is: why does the OP get an apparent address printed here?

Comment: @ChristianHackl it's possible that this is compiler-specific (or platform specific). I certainly wouldn't expect a function pointer to be implicitly cast to bool in a stream.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing any thing to your function average,  float average(float numbers[], float size, float arrayAverage)You should pass your array as first parameter and the size of the array in the second, the third one you dont need it , I recommand you to delete itYour function will be :

```
float average(float numbers[], float size)
{
float average;
        double sum = 0.0;
        for (int x = 0; x < size; x++)
    {
        sum += numbers[x];
        arrayAverage = sum / size;
    }
        return (average);
}
```

and in your main you do a float averageResult = average(array, size);
qDebug()《 averageResult;

Comment: It's a waste of time to have `arrayAverage = sum / size;` inside of the loop, you can move that to the end just outside the loop.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void printArray(int theArray[], int sizeOfarray);

int main()
{
   int array[10] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
   printArray(array, 10);
   return 0;
}

void printArray(int theArray[], int sizeOfarray)
{
   for (int x = 0; x < len(theArray); x++)
  {
    average = average + theArray[x]
  }
  average = average/(len(theArray));
  cout << average;
}
```

Comment: What's `len(theArray)` ? If you haven't coded in C++ for long, don't blindly post wrong codes

Comment: No you're not, you code doesn't compile and you're misleading OP and others saying there's something like `len` function, which infact there's no such function. I suggest you to delete this post or re-write the fixed code.